# How to find right regex for date?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a date like this: "2019" and i want to find a regex for it in javascript. my code return false at all. can you help me please ?

```
let regex = new RegExp('\d{4}');
if regex.test("2019"){
    console.log("true");
} else {
    console.log("false");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error in your syntax is that your are using `RegExp`, in which you would need to double escape `\\d{4}` your pattern.  So `new RegExp('\\d{4}')` should work.

Your regex logic seems OK, but I would recommend that you always use the native regex syntax if possible:

```js
var input = "2019";
if (/^\d{4}$/.test(input)) {
    console.log("true");
}
else {
    console.log("false");
}
```

An exception for using `RegExp` with its string constructor would be a situation where you had to build a regex pattern by piecing together other strings.  In this case, you might have to use `RegExp`.